# Wolfram Client Library: Cannot establish connection with Kernel in second Python function

Tags: python, wolfram-client

I have recently started using the Wolfram Client Library (WCL) for Python in my Linux machine in order to automate running a Mathematica notebook many times.

I have an Anaconda environment `wolfram_env` where I installed the WCL and automated the Mathematica notebook by creating a function that I call many times, let's say from `script_1.py`. For illustration purposes, my function has this structure:

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wlexpr

def run_notebook():
    session = WolframLanguageSession('/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.1/Executables/WolframKernel')
    session.evaluate(wlexpr('n = 3'))
    session.terminate()
```

When calling this from `script_1.py` I have no problems and everything works as expected. However, I want to run this same `run_notebook()` function from `script_2.py` because my actual `run_notebook()` function has an import so I am feeding it other data.

When running `run_notebook()` from `script_2.py` I get the following error:

```
Socket exception: Socket operation aborted.
Failed to start.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/wolfram_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wolframclient/evaluation/kernel/kernelcontroller.py", line 435, in _kernel_start
    response = self.kernel_socket_in.recv_abortable(
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/wolfram_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wolframclient/evaluation/kernel/zmqsocket.py", line 50, in recv_abortable
    raise SocketAborted("Socket operation aborted.")
wolframclient.evaluation.kernel.zmqsocket.SocketAborted: Socket operation aborted.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/wolfram_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wolframclient/evaluation/kernel/localsession.py", line 157, in start
    raise e
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/wolfram_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wolframclient/evaluation/kernel/localsession.py", line 152, in start
    future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/wolfram_env/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/wolfram_env/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/wolfram_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wolframclient/evaluation/kernel/kernelcontroller.py", line 527, in run
    self._safe_kernel_start()
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/wolfram_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wolframclient/evaluation/kernel/kernelcontroller.py", line 366, in _safe_kernel_start
    raise e
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/wolfram_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wolframclient/evaluation/kernel/kernelcontroller.py", line 360, in _safe_kernel_start
    self._kernel_start()
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/wolfram_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wolframclient/evaluation/kernel/kernelcontroller.py", line 455, in _kernel_start
    raise WolframKernelException(
wolframclient.exception.WolframKernelException: Failed to communicate with kernel: /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.1/Executables/WolframKernel.
python-BaseException
```

If I debug `script_2.py` and type `session` inside the `run_notebook()` function after the first line, I get the following description of the `session` variable:

```
<WolframLanguageSession: <WolframKernelController[wolfram-kernel-1 ❌], "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.1/Executables/WolframKernel">>
```

When doing the same from `script_1.py` it shows:

```
<WolframLanguageSession: <WolframKernelController[wolfram-kernel-1 ✅], "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.1/Executables/WolframKernel", pid:10321, kernel sockets: (in:tcp://127.0.0.1:34411, out:tcp://127.0.0.1:37803)>>
```

It seems to me that this second connection cannot be started but I have no clue why. I have tried restarting the computer and running from `script_2.py` directly to ensure no other kernel was active before.

In summary, I am able to establish a connection with the Kernel from the console in Pycharm and from `script_1.py` but not from `script_2.py`.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I found this [issue](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframClientForPython/issues/17) on github. Seems to be related but my technical knowledge is limited so don't understand most of it.

Comment: Please see my answer below, connection error seems to be related to a previous `RuntimeWarning` caused by a `NumPy` function used previously to `WolframLanguageSession()` in `script2.py`.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to reproduce you issue but could not. You're not providing the second script, it I wrote the simplest possible one I could think of and ran it:

script1.py:

```python
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wlexpr

def run_notebook():
    session = WolframLanguageSession('/Applications/Mathematica12.1.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel')
    print(session.evaluate(wlexpr('n = 3')))
    session.terminate()
```

and script2.py:

```python
import script1

script1.run_notebook()
```

I ran the script using: `$ python3 script2.py`, granted that:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

You code is not using `with` statement, so if for some reason it is interrupted before the `terminate()` call, it'll spawn an orphan kernel.

Here is a simple command to look up kernels spawned by the WCL:

```bash
 ps -eaf | grep "WolframKernel.*SlaveKernelPrivateStart" | grep -v grep
```

Comment: ps -eaf | grep "WolframKernel.*SlaveKernelPrivateStart" | grep -v grep

Returns the if of one kernel when run inside the debugger with script_1.py.
Returns nothing when run inside debugger of script_2.py.
Also returns nothing when run outside debuggers

so i think it is not an issue of having multiple kernels

Answer (score 0):

After digging around in the debugger I found the connection was not being established because a specific line of code was being run previously in `script_2.py`. The line causing the error was:

```
replicas = np.array([np.array([np.corrcoef(ts_replica.T) for ts_replica in ts_replicas_gb_batch]) for ts_replicas_gb_batch in ts_replicas_batches])
```

where `ts_replicas_batches` is an `np.array` of shape (1000, 99, 22, 100). This line was producing a RuntimeWarning in the `np.corrcoef` function.

At this stage, I am unsure why this causes kernel connection error. Could be due to the runtime error or some other reason. I will investigate further and try to produce a minimal working example to post here and on the GitHub issues section.